# How do I dynamically assign properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having object like this

```
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "value1";
obj.prop2 = "value2";
```

and string

```
var propName = "prop1"
```

how can I update correct property of name under propName like this

```
obj.{propName} = someValue
```

Comment: `obj[propName] = someValue;`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Don't answer in comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `[]` operator:

```
obj[propName] = someValue;
```